# Given an array, find top 'x' in O(1)

Tags: hash, max

I'm gonna write the problem as I found it and I will then explain what confuses me.

"A teacher is marking his students' work from 0-10 but he only marks with an 8 or above for a certain number 'x'(x=15 for example) of the 'n' students. You are given an array with all the students' marks in random order. Find the 'x' best marks in O(1)."

We certainly have been taught hashing but this requires me to store all the data in a hash table which is definitely not O(1). Maybe we don't have to take the 'conversion' into account? If we do , maybe the coversion combined with the search time after will lead to a method different than hashing.

In that case, leaving O(1) aside , what is the fastest algorithm including both the conversion and the search time?

Comment: Isn't the array itself the solution? :) It contains the x best marks, because it contains x marks :)

Comment: If it's only an unsorted array you have to do linear search

Comment: Wouldn't it be O(n) then? Both the x and n are random, if you change n it will take longer.

Comment: @JohnKatsantas yeah, O(n), you have to look at each element in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: It's not possible.

`O(1)` can only achieved if all of input size, number of necessary comparisons and output size are constants. You may argue that `x` could be treated as constant, but it still doesn't work:

You need to inspect every single input element, all `n` of them, as the random input order does not even allow any heuristics to guess where the `x`th element would be, even if you already had correctly guessed the other `x-1` elements already in constant time.

As the problem is stated, there is no solution which can do it in the upper bounds of `O(1)` or `O(x)`.

---

Let's just assume your instructor corrects his mistake, and gives you a revised version which correctly states `O(n)` as the required upper bound.

In that case your hash approach is (almost) correct. The catch of using a hash function, is that you now need to account for potential collisions on the hash function, which are the reason why hash maps don't work strictly in `O(1)`, but rather only "on average" in `O(1)`.

As you know all possible values (grades from 0-10), you can just allocate buckets with a known index. Inside each bucket you may use linked lists, as they also allow constant time insertions and linear time iteration.